# Looking for a pci wireless card for a ubuntu-based access point. Any recommendations?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, wifi, access-point

I have recently been trying to setup a wireless access point on a small ubuntu server, but the wifi card doesn't seem to be compatible. Its a Dlink DWA-552, which I was hoping would work, but the chipset doesn't seem to support what I'm trying to do.

Is there another wireless card that's currently available that would work? This particular server only has a single PCI slot available, so that may be a limitation. I'd also prefer a card that supports 802.11 N (non-draft), but the important thing is that it works. If it works, I'd be happy with 802.11 N-draft or even 802.11 G.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: If you want a Linux access point, it usually makes more sense to run something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) on access point hardware instead of using a PC as an access point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten the Belkin F5D7050 to work under Ubuntu, though I seem to recall some amount of manual configuration (which may even have included manually downloading and compiling drivers). The particular model that I had (that is to say, there are multiple models of the F5D7050) used either a Ralink or Realtek chipset (exactly which I can't recall), but I understand that some variations use different chipsets, which may or may not be supported, so you'd be taking a risk on that one.

Better yet, I recall there being somewhere on the Ubuntu wiki is a table of compatible wireless cards and adapters that you should take a look at; try starting around here and you might find it (if it even still exists): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs.

Comment: I know some amount of manual configuration will be necessary, but I'd prefer to find a card that won't take too much effort to get working.  I've been working with linux as a hobby for a while now, but there's still a lot I don't know.

Comment: I'll take a look at the Ubuntu wiki you mentioned though.  Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: I decided against trying to build my own access point and just bought another cheap off the shelf access point. Maybe I'll try again when it bites the dust. Thanks for your suggestion though.